# Google Charts - Vertical Axis - Word wrapping on series labels (vertical chart)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am trying to create line breaks or word wrapping on the series labels of my chart. Using '\n' works when I am creating a chart with horizontal orientation:

[image: Word wrapping - horizontal orientation]

However, as soon as I attempt a line break in the vertical orientation, the label ends with '...', even though there is enough width on the vertical series axis (blue outline from mouse hover) for the text:
[image: Word wrapping - vertical orientation]

Notes: I am using Google Charts as my chart generator and Google Sheets as my container.

Thanks!

Code snippet with orientation set as 'vertical':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Metric 1\n Desc of Metric', 20, 28, 38, 45, 50],
          ['Metric 2\n Desc of Metric', 31, 38, 55, 66, 50],
          ['Metric 2\n Desc of Metric', 50, 55, 77, 80, 50],
          ['Metric 2\n Desc of Metric', 77, 77, 66, 50, 50]
          // Treat first row as data as well.
        ], true);

        var options = {
          title : 'Metrics and Values',
          vAxis: {title: 'Values'},
          hAxis: {title: 'Metrics'},
          seriesType: 'candlesticks',
          isStacked: true,
          orientation: 'vertical',
          series: {
            //0: {color: 'white', stroke-width: 4},
            1: {type: 'line', pointShape: 'circle', pointSize: 15, lineWidth: 0}
          },
          chartArea: {  width: "50%", height: "70%" }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try 'upcoming' instead of 'current'.  The axis tick generation has been changed substantially, and it might just work as you desire. Or maybe the newlines are still not used in vertical axis ticks.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but new lines are still not generated with 'upcoming' when loading the Google Chart libraries.